# Parsing xml to objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xml

i'm trying to parse an xml document into 2 NSMutableArrays, but it seems like it is overwriting my array. my xml doc contain 3 objects, but my array only contain 1. Why does it overwrite the previous added objects from the xml doc?

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"playlist"]) {

        title = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"title"];
        listid = [[attributeDict valueForKey:@"id"] intValue];
        lists = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        lists2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [lists addObject:title];
        [lists2 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", listid]];

    }

    NSLog(@"%d", lists.count);

}
```

xml doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Lists>
 <playlist title="Quo Vadis" id="0"/>
 <playlist title="Lord of the Rings" id="1"/>
 <playlist title="Face" id="2"/>
</Lists>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign a new (empty) array to `lists` and `lists2` each time in `didStartElement`,
and therefore overwrite what was previously in those variables.

The arrays must be created only once, before you start the `parse` method.

Comment: So how do this, i cant really seem to find the solution?

Comment: @user3195388: Call `lists = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; lists2 = ...;` just before you call the `parse` method of NSXMLParser, and not in didStartElement.